# Am unable to perform an SVN update on a working copy in Linux getting "Unable to open an ra_local session to URL" error

Tags: linux, svn, version-control, tortoisesvn

I have a Linux server which contains 10 repositories. I have setup a samba share to allow easy access to the repository directory so that I can create repositories via Windows using tortoisesvn's `Create repository here command...`.

The problem is that the repositories were setup using the Windows `file:///` paths and not the HTTP ones using tortoisesvn. I'm using the SVN apache HTTP module. So normally I would specify the repository via `http://servername/svn/myrepos`.

This is all fine in Windows but I need to also use the linux SVN client and am trying to do the following:

```
/usr/bin/svn update /path/to/working/copy
```

But im getting the following error:

```
svn: Unable to open an ra_local session to URL
svn: Unable to open repository 'file:///R:/myrepos/trunk'
```

It seems that the error relates to it trying to find the matching repository for the working copy but it is using the windows file:/// URL's and should be using the HTTP ones.

How can I amend the repositories so that they default to using the http protocol?

Comment: So: the Linux box has the repositories, and they're available over Samba. How have you configured the Apache module? What is /var/svn/myrepos? Is it a repository, or a working copy? It looks like you simply need 'svn switch' to point the working copy at the HTTP address, but your question is unclear as to what's a working copy and what's a repository...

Comment: Your absolutely correct sorry got my examples mixed up!

The command I am trying to run is actually: `/usr/bin/svn update /path/to/working/copy`

Though the error part was correct. It seems to be looking for the corresponding repository but using windows file:/// protocol and not HTTP. This is clearly because I created the repositories via Windows over a network drive.

The problem is still the same.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not certain I understand what the problem is, but if you are looking to keep using a local working copy, while changing the URL you use to access the repository, you want to run `svn switch`:

```
svn switch --relocate file:///my/old/URL http://server/new/URL
```

Comment: It turns out that was exactly the problem. I had created the working copies pointing to the repositories via the file:/// syntax and not the HTTP version. It was not a problem until I needed to use the Linux svn client commands.

I've now switched the working copies over to using http and now everything works.

Answer (score 1):

If you checkout via one url you can then update using a different URL. because the "path" notation is different on both systems you can use the same checkout unless you use the `svn` or `http` protocols. This however has nothing to do with repo creation beyond the fact that you need to expose the repo over one of the platform agnostic protocols. If you can check out from **any client** via `http` or `svn` then youve set everythign up correctly. You just need to blow your checkout away and check it out again using a platform agnostic protocol.

Answer (score 0):

This is probably a permission problem. I had this on a Linux machine with Linux clients on the same machine. Can't you just delete the local svn sandboxen on the Linux machine and re-checkout them?

Comment: I think it is more to do with the way I created the repositories via Windows samba shares and not using the HTTP URL's.